# Ошибка при компиляции(занят другим процессом)

Tags: c#, компиляция

Почему при первой компиляции библиотеки всё проходит хорошо, но при последующих говорит что не могу перезаписать используется другим процесом?
Из-за чего такое может происходить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы наверное используете библиотеку в дизайнере форм. Либо в самой системе. Библиотека перекомпилилась - посмотрели результат, в итоге лок.

Comment: Я удалили ссылку на либу потом заново добавил и всё начало компилироваться...